# How to fix font rendering bug on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, mobile-safari, transparency

I have a header that has a transparent bg and white text when user is at the top of the page and a white bg and blue text when the user is scrolling/anywhere else on the page.

On page load the transparency and font colors work as expected, but if I scroll a bit and scroll quickly back up to the top, something strange happens. The header background stays white and the text appears as a text stroke, with only the outlines showing in blue. It's as if the transition back to the original transparent/white state has gotten stuck halfway. This only happens in Safari on iOS.

I've tried various approaches to rendering the transparent background in Safari but I don't think that's the issue. I tried adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` to transparent elements but that's not it either. I think it might relate to the throttling that happens as the user scrolls or the CSS transitions on the header background and text.

Here is some the SCSS for the header and its transparent variation:

```
.o__header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: $header-height;
  background-color: $white;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    background-color: $header-background-color;
    transition: background-color .3s linear;
  }

  &--transparent {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);

    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      transition: background-color .3s linear;
    }
  }

  .main-menu > .menu-item {

    &.transparent a {
      color: $blue;
    }
  }
}

.main-menu > .menu-item a {
  color: $white;
  text-transform: none;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

And here is the js that controls the transition between the two states:

```
const headerClass = 'o__header--transparent'
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', throttle( checkIfOnTop, 20 ) )

  /**
   * Manages header and hero states based on scroll position.
   */
  function checkIfOnTop () {
    const initialHeight = 10
    const heroHeight = 273

    /**
     * Toggle header transparency based on position.
     */
    function checkScrollPosition () {
      if (
        $( window ).scrollTop() <= initialHeight &&
        !header.classList.contains( headerClass )
      ) {
        header.classList.add( headerClass )

        for ( let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; ++i ) {
          menuItems[i].classList.add( 'transparent' )
        }

      } else if (
        $( window ).scrollTop() > initialHeight &&
        header.classList.contains( headerClass )
      ) {
        header.classList.remove( headerClass )
        hasChildren.classList.remove( 'transparent' )

        for ( let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; ++i ) {
          menuItems[i].classList.remove( 'transparent' )
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Beth. Do you have an URL where we can see your project. This will enable us to reproduce the problem and might help your cause.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Unfortunately it's for a client and I'm not able to share.